# Geom_density_2d_filled() ggplot: (1) how to draw a contour around all points, and (2) how to change gradient colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two questions that I couldn't figure our google out:

Data and ggplot:

```
x = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.3)
y = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 6, sd = 1)
data = merge(x, y, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)

data %>% ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  geom_density_2d_filled(contour_var = "ndensity", bins = 5)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image: ggplot]

(1) how to draw a contour around all points? Currently, 20% of values has the same colour as the background. New layer should be added?

(2) how to change background colour to white and gradient colour to brewer "Blues" palette (all values above 0 should have distinct blue colour from white background)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to decouple the stat from the geom, as the `geom_density_2d_filled()` draws polygons but also includes the outer layer as a rectangle.

Here is my suggestion:

```
x = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.3)
y = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 6, sd = 1)
data = merge(x, y, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)

data %>% ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", contour = TRUE,
                  aes(fill = after_stat(level)), colour = "black",
                  bins = 5) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But if I add geom_point() layer, then some points are outside the contours. Please check the next reply.

Comment: Inside the stat, you can set `breaks = c(0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)` for example instead of `bins`. The first number should be very small, but how small depends on the data. It will leave ugly edges at the data bounds though.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!!! May I ask one more thing? Is there any way to reduce the space between the largest contour and the points? Please check the plot of the last post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'the space between the largest contour and the points' and I don't know what plot of the last post you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to teunbrand! But the points are still outside the contours.

```
set.seed(2)
data %>% ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", contour = TRUE,
                  aes(fill = after_stat(level)), colour = "black",
                  bins = 5)+
  geom_point()+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: The fact points are outside the contour line is in the nature of the analysis. The contours are bins and by definition, there are 5. The 5th (white) is where the points are. If you increase to bins=75, your points will be in blue areas, but that's maybe not what you want it to look like. I might guess you want a trace that kind of looks like it follows the extreme data points like another layer around the fried egg design, but statistically, that won't be very meaningful.