Errors when reversing color scale for geom_density_2d_filled
I'm trying to reverse the color scale for a 2d Density plot so that low density is light and high density is dark (the default is the other way around). Unfortunately, I get an error when I use viridis, and I would greatly appreciate your help.
Minimum working example:
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(2000) + 2, -rexp(1000, rate = 1)), 
                  y = c(rnorm(2000) + 2, -rexp(1000, rate = 1))
                 )

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_density_2d_filled() +
  scale_fill_viridis(direction = -1)

This gives me the error message:
Error in `scale_fill_gradientn()`:
! Discrete values supplied to continuous
  scale.
ℹ Example values: (0.00, 0.01], (0.00, 0.01],
  (0.00, 0.01], (0.00, 0.01], and (0.00, 0.01]
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

If I remove the last line (scale_fill_viridis(direction = -1)), I get a plot, but the color gradient goes in the wrong direction.

Use the option discrete = TRUE:
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_density_2d_filled() +
  scale_fill_viridis(direction = -1, discrete = TRUE)


geom_density_2d_filled expects a discrete color scale since it bins the density into contours, so we need to tell scale_fill_viridis to provide a discrete, rather than continuous color scale.
From the docs:

For discrete == FALSE (the default) all other arguments are as to scale_fill_gradientn or scale_color_gradientn. Otherwise the function will return a discrete_scale with the plot-computed number of colors. [emphasis added]


Thank you very much - it works beautifully. I would like to make one final change - I want to change the palette to start at white and go to darkblue? I tried adding +   scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "darkblue"), but I get the same error about a discrete scale.

@ThomasPhilips This answer looks like it does that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63132320/11944410

Yes it does, and thanks for the pointer. To be honest, the geom_density_2d_filled() + scale_color_viridis() solution looks a bit better in part because it doesn't have heavy distracting contour lines, but some experimentation got me nowhere, but at this point, I think I need to move on. Thanks as always for your generous assistance.

@ThomasPhilips Your welcome! And to get rid of the lines in the other example, just remove , color = "black" ;)
